# Failed to start docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, iptables, nat

I'm trying to run the docker daemon.
But I'm facing the following error.
How to fix it?

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables v1.8.7 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
```

The OS. I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 with the linux upstream kernel 6.4.7+

```
pegasus@pegasus:/boot$ uname -a
Linux pegasus 6.4.7+ #2 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Jul 29 00:27:16 +06 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The details related to my docker version

```
pegasus@pegasus:/boot$ sudo docker version
[sudo] password for pegasus: 
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.2
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        cb74dfc
 Built:             Thu May 25 21:52:14 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:/boot$ sudo docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.2
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.5
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.18.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:/boot$ snap list docker
error: no matching snaps installed
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:/boot$ dpkg -l | grep docker 
ii  docker-buildx-plugin                           0.10.5-1~ubuntu.23.04~lunar                amd64        Docker Buildx cli plugin.
ii  docker-ce                                      5:24.0.2-1~ubuntu.23.04~lunar              amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-cli                                  5:24.0.2-1~ubuntu.23.04~lunar              amd64        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-rootless-extras                      5:24.0.2-1~ubuntu.23.04~lunar              amd64        Rootless support for Docker.
ii  docker-compose-plugin                          2.18.1-1~ubuntu.23.04~lunar                amd64        Docker Compose (V2) plugin for the Docker CLI.
```

I had changed to iptables-legacy but didn't solve the issue.